# Monomorphisms in the category of perfect groups

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

Let **P** be the full subcategory of the category of groups (**Grp**) whose objects are the perfect groups, i.e. those groups for which every element is a product of commutators (but not necessarily itself a commutator). Then it is a well-known fact that **P** is a coreflective subcategory of **Grp**.

> Does there exist a monomorphism in **P** that is not an injective function? If so, is there a full characterization of the monomorphisms in **P**?

In the case of **DivAb**, the category of divisible abelian groups, one well-known example of a non-injective monomorphism is the quotient map $\mathbb{Q} \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. In general, the monomorphisms in **DivAb** are exactly those for which the kernel in **Ab**, the category of all abelian groups, is reduced (i.e. has no nontrivial divisible subgroups).

Dually, of course, there are also many categories with non-surjective epimorphisms, with one well-known example being the inclusion $\mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ in the category of rings.

Comment: @user1729: The mark-up is called a "blockquote". https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang: There are even reflective subcategories of $\mathfrak{G}roup$ that have non-surjective epimorphisms: in the variety generated by $A_5$, any embedding $A_4\hookrightarrow A_5$ is an epimorphism.

Answer (score 2):

A morphism $f : G \to H$ is a monomorphism iff the kernel of $f$ in the usual sense has trivial commutator subgroup, or equivalently is abelian. Examples of such monomorphisms which aren't injective are given by suitable [central extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension#Central_extension). In particular the [universal central extension](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Universal_central_extension) of a perfect group is again perfect. An explicit example is given by the extension $\widetilde{A}_5 \to A_5$ where $\widetilde{A}_5$ is the [binary icosahedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_icosahedral_group).